# First variation of $\int_\Omega |\nabla u |^p$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

How can I calculate the first variation of $F(u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u |^p$?

I cannot expand $|\nabla (u+th)|^p = (|\nabla u |^2 + t^2|\nabla h|^2 + t\nabla u \nabla h)^{\frac p2}$ at all so I don't know how to simplify!!

Comment: Do not simplify. Take the derivative w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: But is it rigourous if I do that? I wanted to show it using the Gateaux derivative formula

Comment: Yes, it is rigourous as long as you also justify the **differentiation under the integral sign** (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J(u) = \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p\, dx$. Then

\begin{align}\frac{J(u + th) - J(u)}{t} &= \frac{1}{t}\int_{\Omega} (|\nabla(u + th)|^p - |\nabla u|^p)\, dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{t} \int_{\Omega} \int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds} |\nabla(u + sth)|^p\, ds\, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{t} \int_{\Omega} \
\int_0^1 p|\nabla u + st\nabla h|^{p-2}(\nabla u + st \nabla h)\cdot (t\nabla h) \, ds\, dx\\
&= \int_{\Omega} \int_0^1 p|\nabla u + st\nabla h|^{p-2}(\nabla u \cdot \nabla h)\, ds\, dx + O(t)
\end{align}

Taking the limit as $t \to 0$ results in

$$J'(u)(h) = \int_\Omega p|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot \nabla h\, dx.$$

Comment: Thangs a lot kobe